# Conditional Formatting to highlight sections in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

How to create a conditional formatting rule for a schedule so that if someone works more than 8 times within 14 days throughout a month, it gets highlighted. For example, If someone works 9 times from the date 4/3 - 4/17, it would highlight that section in that row to show what part of the schedule exceeded 8 days.

Tried to mess with the conditional formatting tab but could not understand it enough. Would result in highlighting entire rows or rows without the variable that was being counted.

The highlighted in the link below is what I want the format to highlight.

Example
[image: Example]

What its supposed to do
[image: What its supposed to do]

Comment: To give any kind of meaningful answer, we'd need to see sample data, expected outcome and your attempts

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I dont have the attempts memorized, I just copied a bunch of different formulas from online and attempted to make it work. But here is a sample and how i want the highlight to work.

Comment: Yep - your example (screenshot) is incongruent with the description; for instance, you state:
• *"if someone works more than 8 times within 14 days throughout a month, it gets highlighted"*

However, you then:
• Select Person 2 in the screenshot for a period which spans 15 days (?)
• Have red column across all 6 people, at a point for which only 4 of them have at least 5 days marked as "D"
• Why is red col on 10? What happens on 10th for Person 2? Only worked 5 days??
• "4/3 - 4/17" - start? (any? only 3rd? where in pic?
• why only 1 day and not *"part of the schedule"

I give up.

Comment: You also say *"The highlighted in the link below is what I want the format to highlight."* -- do you mean the red highlighted? or the selected bit (why show us the red format then if you don't show the conditional format function?). Even if it was selected you wanted to show as red - that still wouldn't make sense because you said earlier you wanted to format the *"part of schedule*" that exceeded 8 days (suggesting you want to format 15th day, and I'm clueless what's supposed to happen after that, is 'counter' supposed to reset after every 14 days within month?

Comment: @JB-007 The highlighted section is from the 2nd to the 15th, that is 14 days. The red is just marked as a holiday for everyone. It has nothing to affect on the schedule. And i want to highlight the section that is equal to or greater than 8 days of work within a 14 day period. Meaning from the 1-14, 2-15, 3-16, etc. One person cannot have or exceed 8 days.

Comment: Maybe make your example clearer and include several scenarios when you do

Comment: @MaxM so red is completely irrelevant (that was a red herring indeed!). My advice is to exclude such (especially when this can be mistaken for something very relevant - e.g. conditional formatting vs. highlighting etc.)

So would this be the Q you're after?
*"How to apply conditional formatting to any row that comprises more than 8 "d's" in any consecutive 14d during the month"*?

• the only bit I still don't get is whether you want this to trigger conditional formatting over the entire 14d in question, or only *"from the point where 8 days was exceeded to the end of the resp. period"*?

Comment: @JB-007 It is throughout the entire month period. At any point during the 30-31 day period, There cannot be 8 ds in any consecutive14 day periods

Comment: @MaxM - alrighty - see below mate

Comment: (would strongly recommend taking tips above to make Q clearer/without red herrings and the like - more examples; explain it like you would to a 7 year old - that's how much we know about what you're trying to achieve when we start reading your Q! ) ta

Comment: PS - your link is good - should've been the main (probably only) screenshot - not sure if you inserted it afterwards but it's undoubtedly helpful / a bit clearer.  ta

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9h_ExRQTLx6CPfUmEkw?e=KguV5o)/screenshot(s) refer:

Conditional formatting function:

```
=--(SUM(--(C7:$AG7="d")*(--C$6:$AG$6<=--C$6+MIN(EOMONTH($C$6,0)-$C$6+1,$B$4-1)))>$B$3)
```

[image: Conditional formatting function]

[image: Region applied to]

---

**Checks**

```
=--(COUNTIFS(C7:OFFSET(C7,0,13),"d")>8)
```

[image: Checks with 8 day max]

---

**Notes**

- max: 3 in first function; 8 in checks
- rolling: Q stated 14, change as desired
- Assumes full month (hence `eomonth` above), change to required end period as req.
- Further refinement req. if 14 day rolling period not meant to span 2 different months/years etc.
- Cannot use reference function (e.g. `offset`) in conditional format equation for some silly reason - hence refined approach in checks not used initially
- Number format applied to checks section: see screenshot below

  *"d";; * ""*

[image: Number format - checks section]

---

Comment: How come it highlighting only 5 in the first row, 5 would be fine in the normal situation. I just need it to highlight the entire parts of it when it reaches 8 within the 14-day period. Also, whats up with the single highlight in Q9

Comment: Note the parameters for the respective screenshot(s) - I’ve used a threshold of 3 days not 8 for first one. What do you expect (I’ve explicitly stated this in the comprehensive notes). What is up with it is that there are no further 14 consecutive days beyond that point with more than 3 consecutive working days.  I say in my notes that it extends to end of month / no carry over as it spans two months requires adjustment to cater for this. As you get to within 14 days of a given month, the 14 day rolling period naturally diminishes (1 day for every day after the 15th). Read Every pt in my notes

Comment: It works as you intend it to with the desired parameters - allowing for the salient points in my notes section. I do checks to confirm this (also provided).  If you want the 14 day period to extend beyond end of month (the description in Q left a multitude of questions / variations wide open, requiring much guess work on my part to put even this together - I wasn’t the only one that struggled..) - then you’ll need to adjust the formula appropriately. For instance replace MIN(EOMONTH($C$6,0)-$C$6+1,$B$4-1) with just $B$4-1, and 14 day period will look beyond the end of the schedule.

Comment: I’ll just add that you should consider the trade off in allowing the 14 day period to “roll over” the end of the schedule being used, as the 3 or 8 (or whatever) threshold will by definition diminish in the same fashion as the 14 days (on basis used in original submission).